# Disable 'Your connection is not secure' in Firefox

Tags: firefox, ssl

I know this is bad practice, but I need to be able to disable the 'You connection is not secure' message in Firefox. Various network changes were made at work, and now virtual machine proxies will not allow Firefox to contact the internal certificate validation.

Until IT get around to fixing this (which can take ages as it is low priority), every HTTPS site requires you to add an exception. Is there any way in the about:config settings or anywhere else in Firefox where this warning can be disabled?

Comment: I don't have anything to test this out on offhand but try this: go to `about:config` > type `insec` in the search box > go down to `security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled` and change its value to `false`.

Comment: Be advised that this will probably push the issue further down on IT's priority list, as the problem has now been 'fixed'.

Comment: @n8te there is no such field. I am using Firefox 50.1.0 for Linux Mint

Comment: Oh ok. Well, I'm using Firefox 52.0.1 on openSUSE

Comment: @Mike159 add it then. Right click, New boolean, Enter the string name from above, then set it to false.

Comment: Aside from what @MarcksThomas said also keep in mind that this will affect not just your intranet sites but also internet sites.

Comment: since this thing was easy skippable in older Firefox Versions it may be a better option to just use a second older installed or even better portable Version (https://portableapps.com/support/firefox_portable) of Firefox - that way you also can easily remove it again after they fixed it. also if you cant install anything on your work pc you can even have the portable version on a usb-pen

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the step to remove the warning:

1) Open a new tab and type the URL as about: config.
2) Click the button “I accept the risk!”
3) You will see a list of Preferences.
4) Search for “security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled” using the search box.
5) Make Preferences value to “false” by double clicking on the row.

A detailed blog :http://sforsuresh.in/disable-insecure-password-warning-firefox/

Comment: That doesn't work. Your suggestion is for disabling the warning drop-down on input fields. The original question is asking about disabling the "Your connection is not secure" page that appears when an SSL certificate can't be validated.

Comment: Works for me actually

Comment: Solution doesn't work, ff 63.0.1